# Why does pop() function alters a list value of dictionary but capitalize() can't change case of a string value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to alter values without reassigning any value in the dictionary. But it seems that it works for pop function and not with string functions.

I tried with other list functions and works the same as pop. Looks that list and string work differently when used as values.

```
my_dict={"Rank":[1,2,3],"Name":"John"}
my_dict.get("Rank").pop()
print(my_dict)
my_dict.get("Name").capitalize()
print(my_dict)
```

Comment: `list` objects are mutable. Some methods on lists are mutator methods, that is, they work "in-place". `.pop` is one such method. `str` objects are immutable. That simply means *they lack mutator methods*, so you know that non of their methods will work "in-place". So `.capitalize()` simply returns a new string, which is immediately discarded (since you don't assign it to anything)

Answer (score 1):

`my_dict.get("Rank")` is a mutable list, and you're only using a reference to it. Any changes you make to it, including `pop()`, will be reflected everywhere.

`my_dict.get("Name")` is an immutable string. You can't change it, and so `capitalize()` will return a new string, not modify the existing one.

Comment: But dictionaries in Python are Mutable.     my_dict.get("Name") value is not stored separately but in dictionary object itself.

Comment: @PrashantKumarGupta yes, but you never mutated the dictionary anywhere. You *do* mutate the `list` object, and you *dont* mutate the `str` object, because `str` objects are immutable.

Comment: Why does this also not work `my_dict={"Rank":[1,2,3],"Name":"John","Salary":100.0}
my_dict.get("Rank")[1].__add__(1)
print(my_dict)`

Comment: @PrashantKumarGupta for the very same reason: `int` objects are immutable. This none of their methods work in-place. As an aside, you should pretty much never use a double-underscore method directly like that

Comment: See also e.g. [Python difference between mutating and re-assigning a list](/q/56308475/).

Answer (score 0):

It's because:

- `list.pop` - operates (*in-place*) on the list itself (removing the (last) element) and thus modifies it
- [[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Types - str.**capitalize**()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) - doesn't operate on the string, but returns a (modified) copy, leaving the original one unchanged

To correct your problem, use:

```py
my_dict["Name"] = my_dict["Name"].capitalize()
```

Answer (score 0):

`caplitalize()` returns a str object. If you want to update the value you need to push this back to the dict.

```
my_dict["Name"] = my_dict.get("Name").capitalize()
```